# Unable to descrypt mp3 file via gpg

Tags: linux, encryption, gnupg, openpgp

I'm trying to decrypt a binary/mp3 file of 100Mb of size.

```
gpg2 --decrypt my_audio.mp3.gpg
```

And it results into a long binary text in the terminal and it won't create a pure mp3 file:

[binary text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E77cT.png)

What's wrong with it? How can I decrypt the file?

Answer (score 1):

That is the mp3. Try this

```
gpg2 --decrypt my_audio.mp3.gpg > my_audio.mp3
```

Answer (score 0):

From the man page:

```
--decrypt
-d
Decrypt the file given on the command line (or STDIN if no file is   
specified) and write it to STDOUT (or the file specified with --output).
```

So use either

```
gpg2 --decrypt my_audio.mp3.gpg > my_audio.mp3
```

or

```
gpg2 --decrypt --output my_audio.mp3 my_audio.mp3.gpg
gpg2 --decrypt -o my_audio.mp3 my_audio.mp3.gpg
```